# Wordpress `get_the_post_thumbnail` Source URL

Tags: php, wordpress

This will return a fully formatted HTML `<img ... >` tag.

```
$thumb_id = $post->ID;

$pictureLink = get_the_post_thumbnail($thumb_id, 'medium');
```

**What function can I use to get the 'src' tag value?**

I tried some other WP functions for attachments but these did not return anything useful for some reason.

I will accept a WP function or a parser that will extract the `src` tag's value.

**Update:**
Parser that will extract the `src` tag's value.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($pictureLinkHtml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$pictureLink = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a lot easier than parsing it. First you need to get the attachment ID from the post ID. then you can grab the source which includes the URL, width and height. Here is [more information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).

```
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'large');

echo $image[0];
```

Comment: @BAR what doesn't work? This is tested and proven to work.

Comment: It does not return the right url.  No idea why the variance.

Comment: `get_post_thumbnail_id` needs the post ID so make sure that is being supplied then check that the thumbnail is large enough to have a large size or remove it because it is optional. You should then get the thumbnail that is attached to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'medium');

if ($thumb_src) {
    list($thumb_src) = $thumb_src;
    echo "Source of thumb is $thumb_src";
}
```

See [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) reference.